# Discord.js slash commands type 5

Tags: discord.js

So I have been developing a bot recently and I have implemented the slash commands into said bot. I have come across the need for a type 5 command "response" but I can't seem to find good documentation on the slash commands. I can't seem to make it "stop thinking". Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I found that you need to edit the interaction response (https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#interaction-response) but I'm not using webhooks I'm using a bot and I don't want to have to get another npm library if I don't have to. So how do I edit my interaction?

Comment: what if you just `return` on the function? A code snippet would also be nice to view to see what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this, if you want to know how I did here is some code.

if your interaction responder looks like this:

```js
if (interaction.data.name === 'whatever') {
    whatever.whatever (interaction)//i am using a command handler to put 
    //the actual event into a different file
  }
```

and your "interaction message sender" looks like this: (notice it's type 5)

```js
module.exports.whatever = (interaction) => {
    client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
        data: {
            type: 5
        }
    })
};
```

then it will say "{botname} is thinking" with a little ellipses, and after 15 minutes if nothing happens it will fail the interaction. If you want to make it "stop thinking" you have to edit the message. I am using the axios npm library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and if you just put in this code it should edit your interaction message. this goes at the top of your file with your requirements:

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const appId = ''//bot id goes here
```

and somewhere near the bottom of your file maybe put in this:

```js
const editInteraction = async (client, interaction, response) => {
    const data = typeof response === 'object' ? { embeds: [ response ] } : { content: response };
    const channel = await client.channels.resolve(interaction.channel_id);
    return axios
        .patch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/webhooks/${appId}/${interaction.token}/messages/@original`, data)
        .then((answer) => {
            return channel.messages.fetch(answer.data.id)
        })
};
```

then you will have the basic code structure to edit the message, now you just need to *edit* the message. to do that, in your code, do this:

```js
  if (interaction.data.name === 'whatever') {
    whatever.whatever (interaction).then(m => {
    editInteraction(client, interaction, '>:(')//this will actually edit the message so 
    //instead of " >:( " put in what you want to edit you message to be
      })
  }
```

then you can run that command and it will say the bot is thinking then after whatever event you want to run it will edit it to say whatever!